# Using Bower with Express

Tags: express, gulp, bower

I'm a late arrival to the Bower scene. I thought I'd try it with my current Express project. I installed it, and created the `.bowercc` and `bower.json` file per instructions. I installed a Bootstrap skin I planned on using, which brought with it jQuery. The thing is, you get tons of files, and I'd like to use just the minified versions of JS, CSS and fonts.

After scowering the net, I found a lot about using gulp or grunt to sift through the files, and pipe them to the `/public` folder Express provides. My question is: how do you do it properly? How do I get just the files I need there? Or am I better off foregoing bower and just downloading the zip file, picking up the end result and placing in the `/public` folder?

Comment: Don't worry about other files, just include necessary to your project: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">`. During your build tasks in grunt/gulp you will minify and concatenate scripts and css.

Comment: I don't want the entire source, samples and documentation of a JS library I use to end up in my git repo.

Comment: Of course, that is why you should not commint bower_components in repositiry. You would have `bower_components` in .gitignore.

Comment: and how do the components find their way to my prod/heroku server if they're not in the repo?

Comment: you commit the concatenated/compiled versions of them to the repository.

Comment: @KevinB that's exactly what I want to do, but is that a manual step? I.e. copy .min files from the bower_components/..../dist/js folder to /public manually, or is there some gulp magic?

Comment: It's up to you how to organize build process. There is no magic. But you will need to concat uglify sources, copy them to dist folder, etc.

Comment: gulp can definitely take care of the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the comments, it seems like the answer is yes - manual job is required to get your components distributeables to your `public` folder. Using gulp will automate it, but basically it'd be a hit-and-miss at first, requiring some fine tuning. In case someone lands on this question, here's the solution I went with:

1) Provide package overrides in the bower.json file to ake sure only the minified files are exposed:

```
{
  "name": "charlie",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-material-design": "~0.3.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap-material-design": {
      "main": ["**/dist/js/*.min.js", "**/dist/css/*.min.css", "**/dist/fonts/*"]
    },
    "jquery": {
      "main": "**/dist/jquery.min.js"
    }
  }
}
```

2) Use the `main-bower-files` gulp package to grab those "mains" and distribute them to the final locations. Here's my gulpfile.json (just the bower part:

```
var bower = require('main-bower-files');
var gulpFilter = require('gulp-filter');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');


var getDist = function(vendor) {
  var publicDir = 'public';
  var dist = vendor ? publicDir + '/vendor' : publicDir;
  return {
    dir: dist,
    css: dist + '/css/',
    js: dist + '/js/',
    fonts: dist + '/fonts/'
  };
};

gulp.task('cleanVendor', function() {
  return gulp.src(getDist(true).dir, {read: false})
    .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('bower', ['cleanVendor'], function() {
  var dist = getDist(true);
  var jsFilter = gulpFilter('**/*.js');
  var cssFilter = gulpFilter('**/*.css');
  var fontsFilter = gulpFilter(['**/*.woff*', '**/*.eot', '**/*.svg', '**/*.ttf']);
  return gulp.src(bower())
    .pipe(fontsFilter)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dist.fonts))
    .pipe(fontsFilter.restore())
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dist.js))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dist.css))
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore());
});
```

3) In your HTML file, include `/vendor/js/blah.min.js` or `/vendor/css/blah.min.css`

**Note**: the annoying part was that I had to specify every font extension in the `fontsFilter`. I tried using `'**/fonts/*'` but `main-bower-files` returns a flat list of files, and if you provide the `{base: 'mybase'}` parameter, it returns a tree, meaning you get the entire tree structure per file - anyone who can come up with a fix, is invited to submit an answer.